# how to determine which ad is being displayed

Tags: admob, ads, facebook-audience-network

I'm building an android app wherein native ads (using admob or facebook) will be displayed and users will be asked questions related to the ad's image. How can I figure out which ad will be displayed so that I can prepare questions related to that image? Is it possible with any other ad network than facebook/google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not allowed when using Audience Network.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/policy

> 6. Don’t "crawl", "spider", index or in any non-transitory manner store or cache information obtained from any ads.

Comment: Yep. AdMob ads should also not be scanned or crawled by the presenting app.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Thanks RedBrogdon.

Answer (score 1):

In Admob website you are able to check wich kind of ads you want to display.

[image]

I sugest you to check [AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/#topic=2745287) and Facebook ads to see if it is legal.
But selecting categories will show just the categories that you want on AdMob.

Comment: Thanks Alisson for the reply.